# Visual Studio C++ Console Application builds and runs but creates no EXE file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe

Just like in the title. The code builds correctly and I can run it in VS but when i go to the output directory there's no EXE. Also, if I change the output directory like this: $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\XXX\ it doesn't even create the XXX folder.

CLR is turned off, output format is set to .exe. I checked 100 times, I am looking in the correct directory . Changing to debug/release or x64/x32 does not help. Antivirus has nothing to do with it either.

[image]

Comment: Check task manager file path of the run executable

Comment: You are looking at the project build directory, the final executable is stored in the solution directory.  That's what $(SolutionDir) means.

Comment: @HansPassant a subdirectory of the solution directory depending on x86 or x64

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, When I do that it says it's at ...\ConsoleApplication10\x64\Release\XXX. But of course there is no XXX there. When I remove the XXX it does not help either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was stated by Hans Passant, you have to check for the executable in $(SolutionDir)/$(Configuration): that would be in either `../ConsoleApplication10/Release` or it might be also represented with the target architecture, then e.g. `../ConsoleApplication10/x64`

Comment: OMG I now get what you meant. This is correct, though I think it's stupid it makes another x64/Release folder in the solution directory and puts the EXE there...